# React Three Fiber: how to set shape as node of a graph and change the color of the links

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I have this code:

```
import { SpriteMaterial, Sprite, TextureLoader } from "three";
import logoTexture from "../assets/react.svg";
import { useMemo, useEffect } from "react";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import { useFrame, useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
import ThreeForceGraph from "three-forcegraph";
import { gData } from "./data";

const loader = new TextureLoader();

const nodeToThree = () => {
  const imgTexture = loader.load(logoTexture);
  const material = new SpriteMaterial({ map: imgTexture });
  const sprite = new Sprite(material);
  sprite.scale.set(50, 50);
  return sprite;
};

export default function Graph() {
  const { scene } = useThree();
  const graph = useMemo(() => {
    return new ThreeForceGraph().graphData(gData).nodeThreeObject(nodeToThree);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    while (scene.children.length > 0) {
      scene.remove(scene.children[0]);
    }
    scene.add(graph);
  }, [graph, scene]);

  useFrame(() => {
    graph.tickFrame();
  });
  return (
    <>
      <OrbitControls />
    </>
  );
}
```

based on this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/three-force-graph-r3f-1mgxq

How could I:

- change the node that instead of being an image, being a ***sphereGeometry***?
- change the color of the links between the nodes of the graph?